# Is there an extremely simple CMS with In-Place Editing?

Tags: cms, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a very limited, very simple CMS that allows non-techies to maintain a simple website consisting of maybe 4-6 editable pages.

It should

- use a WYSIWYG editor
- only support static pages
- have an editable menu bar
- behave like a wiki - edit button or tab on a page
- no administration back-end
- be based on PHP, MySQL/MariaDB

I've already considered Mediawiki with a theme, but I believe its markup system is hard-coded, making a WYSIWYG editor difficult to implement.

Googling for "simple in-place editing CMS" and similar terms brings up CMSes that I already consider too complicated for my audience.

Comment: Of possible interest to you: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/WYSIWYG_editor

Comment: Product recommendation questions are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't checked out [opensourcecms.com](http://opensourcecms.com), that may be a good place to get started.  I have not used it myself, but I have recently heard good things about [Concrete5](http://concrete5.org), it may be worth a look

Comment: Funny, I did try Concrete5 just a few hours after my post and, after checking out various other CMSes, decided to go with it. If possible, I would go for an even simpler solution, but out of everything I tried, only Mediawiki and Concrete5 fit the bill. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Mediawiki with http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FCKeditor_%28Official%29 might be what you want if you're already comfortable with mediawiki.

Also, I would suggest you look into WordPress. WYSIWYG editor, configurable menus, plugins for just about anything you like, tons of themes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Plone at all? We currently use it for our systems documentation as it is great with the search features. It also has an editor, and you can customise which buttons are shown for users so you don't clutter the screen with too much.

Comment: plone is everything but not simple... and last time i've checked it was pythong/own-db-based not php/mysql.

Comment: True, my mistake. Was writing a quick answer and not thinking properly. Good luck

Comment: Well, it's not completely off the chart - I'm looking for something that is (or can be made) simple for users. The install and configuration side isn't that much of an issue. Regarding Plone, I did take a look at it about two years ago, but the entire Python + Zope infrastructure was pretty difficult to grasp.